# C++ distinguish Functor and Value template argument

Tags: c++, templates, functor, overloading

In general I'm having some trouble understanding functors, as I'm fairly new with template programming.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is the following, I'm trying to have a function that takes a Functor and an overloaded function that takes a value.

ideally:

```
template<typename ValueType>
int function(ValueType v)
{
    v + 1;
    ...
}

template<typename Functor>
int function(Functor f)
{
    f();
    ...
}
```

I would be fine taking a performance hit with something like taking an std::function as parameter, but I especially want to be able to take a lambda as parameter.

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to achieve is to allow a construct I'm building to have lazy evaluation when necessary:

```
construct.option(1)
construct.option([](){ return 5;})
construct.value()
```

With the construct choosing which argument's value to get when option is called. (likely with an extra argument determining whether that option is chosen)

To be clear, as soon as this option call is done, it knows whether to evaluate the expression or not.

Also if the argument overloads the () operator, I want to call it, regardless of it overloads the + 1 too.

Comment: You can differentiate between them with SFINAE (whether the parameter has a `operator()` or not).

Comment: What is the reason you need to use templates?

Comment: does it have to be overloads? The problem with your approach is that for `function(x);` it (currently) isnt possible to know which overload should be chosen. There are ways to fix it, but not sure if it is worth the effort. Can't you rename it to `functionTakingValue` and `functionTakingFunctor` ?

Comment: btw smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you describe seems to be what you think is the solution to a problem we dont know. What do you actually want to achieve? Maybe you can give an example for code calling the method

Comment: What if an argument `x` supports _both_ `x+1` and `x()` ? The two are not exclusive. That's BTW why there is `std::find` for value types and `std::find_if` for functors.

Comment: btw if passing a value is the exception, then maybe you can have only the function that takes a functor and for values you pass a `[](){ return x;}`. Not sure, but i wouldnt expect a big performance hit when optimizations are enabled

Comment: Edited to make it more clear, but the SFINAE way seems the way to go here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
// overload taking functor f(int)
template<typename Func>
std::result_of_t<Func(int)>   // or std::invoke_result_t<> (C++17)
function(Func const&func)
{
    return func(0);
}

// overload taking value of builtin arithmetic type
template<typename ValueType>
enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<ValueType>::value, ValueType>
function(Value const&val)
{
    return val;
}
```

Comment: In C++17 you have [std::is_invocable(_r)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) which is a bit better than checking the conversion to `std::function`.

Comment: @Holt Actually, checking for conversion to `std::function` is not necessary even with C++11.